# Save Form data to database Gives error: Call to a member function addData() on boolean

Tags: error, magento-1, adminform, save

Have the following fields in my from:

```
    protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $helper = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array('legend' => $helper->__('Select Social Icons'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'facebook',
        'label' => $helper->__('Facebook'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('google', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'google',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('twitter', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'twitter',
        'label' => $helper->__('Twitter'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('linkedin', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'linkedin',
        'label' => $helper->__('Linkedin'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('yelp', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yelp',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yelp'),
        ));


    if (Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->getData());
    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Here is my Modal:

```
     class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Review extends       Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
     {
    public function _construct()
     {
     parent::_construct();
     $this->_init('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review');
    }
   }
```

And here is my controller function to save data:

```
public function saveAction()
    {

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
if ( $data ) {

    print_r($data);

    $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
    $model = Mage::getModel('reviewmycompany/review');
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    try {
        if ( $id ) {
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $model->addData($data);
        //saves data
        $model->save();

        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Data was saved'));

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);

        if ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('back') ) {
            $params = array('id' => $model->getId());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', $params);
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/list');
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        if ( $model && $model->getId() ) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
                'id' => $model->getId()
            ));
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/new');
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

When I save form it gives following error:

> Call to a member function addData() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-new\app\code\community\OptFirst\ReviewMyCompany\controllers\Adminhtml\AdminformController.php
>   on line 77

I need help to solve this issue so the form successfully save data to database table

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call your model this way:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review');
```

You can find correct model alias in the `{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/config.xml` file in the *global -> models* section.

*Example, the model alias is `test`:*
[image: example]

**Update:**

If the `$data` is not an empty array after the `$model->addData($data);` your code `print_r($model->getData());` should return at least the `$data` parameters (can be more, but not less).

Comment: Oh.. that was the issue too thanks for this.. but now when i print the model it gives empty array @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Comment: I did like this print_r($model->getData()); and it returns Array ( )

Comment: @Xabby On what line?

Comment: @Xabby. Don't mix the questions and dont spawn additional questions once you got a right answer. If this solved your problem mark the answer as accepted and ask a different question for your different problem.

Comment: Here i print the model and it returs the empty array
$this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        $model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review');
        print_r($model->getData());  @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Comment: @Xabby Becouse you are using an empty model, try to load it. Something like this: `$model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->load($existing_id_here);` and after that call your print-data code `print_r($model->getData());`

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau  sorry to bother again.. what will my  $exi‌​sting_id_here in case Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Comment: @Xabby it should be the model entity id (like 1 or 2 or something else)